# Jacoco and Sonar code coverage?

Tags: maven, jenkins, selenium-rc, sonarqube, jacoco

**Using :** JaCoCo 0.5.3, Maven2, Sonar 2.14, sonar-maven-plugin 1.8, SùartGWT 3.0
**Currently trying to :** Get code coverage on Sonar of my Selenium unit tests.
**Problem :** Code coverage doesn't move from 0% although the sensor is launched properly, analyse the jacoco.exec which is correctly generated.
**Ressources :** https://gist.github.com/2888912 The pom.xml

It's been about 2 weeks I'm trying to get code coverage. I upgraded the Sonar from 2.10 to 2.14, changed every single sonar property, tried the plugin jacoco (for maven) and I still DON'T get any results. So if someone had the same problems and found the solution, could you please tell me how you amde it work ?

I'm quite sure my tests must generate at least 0.5% of code coverage. My Selenium tests are actually executed in SeleniumTestLoginEntry.java, does it have any incidence ? Must I call it TestLoginEntry.java ? (The tested class is LoginEntry.java)
I'm using surefire to start the javaagent of JaCoCo (see the  tag) and it actually GENERATES the jacoco.exec.

Please give me some help, I'm totally lost I have only one week left to make it work... :(
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try with: [Code coverage plugins](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Code+coverage+plugins) manual?

Comment: @ajozwik Yes I already read that. I already added the properties.

Comment: Add only `<sonar.core.codeCoveragePlugin>jacoco</sonar.core.codeCoveragePlugin>` to your pom. Delete java agent, jacoco section (only leave jacoco plugin version). Sonar will create own pom file, find it in `${basedir}/target/sonar/sonar-pom.xml`

Answer (score 4):

I'm in a slightly different setup than you are, using Ant and Sonar 3.01, but... there was one property that did the trick for me, that seemed to be almost entirely undocumented when I looked.  I notice the wiki pages have had updates in the last couple of days, which may have changed the doc situation.

```xml
<property name="sonar.core.codeCoveragePlugin" value="jacoco" />
<property name="sonar.jacoco.reportPath" value="${test.log.dir}/jacoco.exec"/>
```

Setting `sonar.jacoco.reportPath` explicitly to the file, not a directory, was what finally worked for me.

Comment: In fact I think : I don't launch the Jacoco agent at the right time or my tests don't generate code coverage since the jacoco:report (a maven goal that generates a HTML page with coverage) tells me that there is a 0% code coverage. Are you using smartGwt and if you are, could you give me some example ? By the way thanks for your answer, I'll try that.

Comment: I had trouble getting the sonar task to launch tests and collect jacoco data in one step, so I decided to separate those activities.  I launch the Jacoco agent as a part of running unit tests, which is a separate step (target in Ant-speak, goal in maven) I complete before starting anything with sonar.  So I can run a reporting task (which must be the ant entry to maven's jacoco:report) and see results before populating sonar.
By the time I'm running the sonar target, I have populated jacoco.exe file(s).  From your description, it sounds like you're not getting any Jacoco results at all.

Comment: That's right, jacoco:report does not give me a result. I don't know if : I'm not launching the agent correctly or my tests don't generate code coverage.

Comment: It sounds like you need to start with solving the jacoco problem, and get to where jacoco:report shows you something.  Once you have that, then you can look at loading data into sonar.  I don't use maven, so I'm just guessing, but I suspect there's something you have to do to run unit tests with jacoco enabled.  Sorry I can't be more help in that area.