# How do I configure JaCoCo with Sonar

Tags: maven-3, sonarqube, jacoco

How do I configure JaCoCo with Sonar 2.3 and Maven 3.0.4?

My project is a multi-module Maven project. My top level pom has the following:

```
    <sonar.core.codeCoveragePlugin>jacoco</sonar.core.codeCoveragePlugin>
    <sonar.dynamicAnalysis>reuseReports</sonar.dynamicAnalysis>
```

After running mvn sonar:sonar I am getting 0% Code Coverage reported in Sonar. I should be seeing at least 50%. Note I do see the jacoco.exec in the target folder of each child project.

Answer (score 1):

Consider upgrading Sonar - the current version is 3.2, and has JaCoCo as it's native code coverage module.

Also, see https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/tree/master/projects/code-coverage/ut for lots of examples

Answer (score 1):

They have modified the GitHub project structure. New link with the examples is:

https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/tree/master/projects/languages/java/code-coverage/ut

Answer (score -1):

Hi there are some very interesting articles describing exactly your case. Here's the list
http://www.sonarsource.org/measure-coverage-by-integration-tests-with-sonar-updated/
http://johndobie.blogspot.gr/2011/06/maven-multi-module-with-sonar-and.html
http://johndobie.blogspot.gr/2011/06/seperating-test-code-coverage-with.html
And one relevant question
[Jacoco and Sonar code coverage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10933407/jacoco-and-sonar-code-coverage)
Hope you find them useful

Comment: It looks like Sonar can only process a single JaCoCo report file. Not very good.